# Write Test for Flutter FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

In my app after press button it's opening another screen, a form (StatefulWidget) which is loading from FutureBuilder. I need to write test class for this, 
But in log it says when executing form is not finished build. This is test code,

```
await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.add));
  await tester.pump(const Duration(seconds: 1));

   await tester.runAsync(() async {
    when(tester.tap(find.byKey(Key("add_new_form")))).thenAnswer((_) => Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 30), () => []));
    await tester.pumpAndSettle(Duration(seconds: 10), EnginePhase.build, Duration(minutes: 1));

    await tester.pump();
    await tester.pump(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    await tester.pump(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    expect(find.byKey(Key("form")), findsOneWidget);
  });
```

how to write test class for flutter FutureBuilder ?? I have seen two questions relates to FutureBuilder but they are different from my situation. Any help would be appreciated.